# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: Can't find variable ErrorTitle

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I'm trying to create an app that uses Firebase authentication. I want to change the error messages, as I feel that the error messages aren't user friendly. I've created this login function, but I'm getting this error:
`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: errorTitle`

This is the code i've got:

```
try {
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  });
  let user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  if (user) {
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
} catch(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'auth/invalid-email':
      errorTitle = 'Invalid Email';
      errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid email address';
      break;
    case 'auth/user-not-found':
      errorTitle = 'No User Found';
      errorMessage = 'This email does not exist as a user. Please sign up if you want to gain access.';
      break;
    case 'auth/wrong-password':
      errorTitle = 'Wrong Password';
      errorMessage = 'The password is incorrect. Please try again.';
      break;
    default:
      errorTitle = 'Error';
      errorMessage = 'An undefined error happened.';
  }
  this.setState({
    loading: false
  });

  Alert.alert(
    errorTitle,
    errorMessage,
  );
}
```

I can't seem to understand what is causing the error. I've got a try/catch block. This is a React Native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you haven't declared `errorTitle` or `errorMessage` anywhere in the code. You're trying to assign a value to something that doesn't exist.

Try just adding `let errorTitle` and `let errorMessage` just above your `switch` statement